# RSpec why is before(:each) never executed?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have this simple code

```
require 'json'

module Html
  class JsonHelper
    attr_accessor :path

    def initialize(path)
      @path = path
    end

    def add(data)
      old = JSON.parse(File.read(path))
      merged = old.merge(data)
      File.write(path, merged.to_json)
    end
  end
end
```

and this spec (reduced as much as I could while still working)

```
require 'html/helpers/json_helper'

describe Html::JsonHelper do
  let(:path) { "/test/data.json" }
  subject { described_class.new(path) }

  describe "#add(data)" do
    before(:each) do
      allow(File).to receive(:write).with(path, anything) do |path, data|
        @saved_string = data
        @saved_json = JSON.parse(data)
      end

      subject.add(new_data)
    end

    let(:new_data) { { oldestIndex: 100 } }
    let(:old_data) { {"test" => 'testing', "old" => 50} }

    def stub_old_json
      allow(File).to receive(:read).with(path).and_return(@data_before.to_json)
    end

    context "when given data is not present" do
      before(:each) do
        puts "HERE"
        binding.pry
        @data_before = old_data
        stub_old_json
      end

      it "adds data" do
        expect(@saved_json).to include("oldestIndex" => 100)
      end

      it "doesn't change old data" do
        expect(@saved_json).to include(old_data)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`HERE` never gets printed and binding.pry doesn't stop execution and tests fail with message `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /test/data.json`

This all means that before(:each) never gets executed.

Why?
How to fix it?

Comment: Does using a relative path work? `./test/data.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not print desired message because it fails at the first `before` block. [Rspec doc about execution order](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-5/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks)

It fails because you provided an absolute path, so it is checking `/test/data.json`

Either use relative path to the test ie. `../data.json` (just guessing),
or full path.
In case of rails:
`Rails.root.join('path_to_folder_with_data_json', 'data.json')`